# How to get ios app version from any ios client

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, api, version

I have a rails API, consumed by an ios client. I made some changes to the API that requires an ios app update to work on the client's mobile, but before inforcing the update we want to try and see if we can get the app ios version the client is using this way we can filter and only make the new feature available for the clients who have the last app version?

Comment: What is the client sending over to you?

Comment: Don't forget to mark an answer as "top answer" to close your question. If none of the answers helped, comment on them to discuss them further

Answer (score 0):

You can't read this from a user agent string or similar, if thats what you are asking. You would need the iOS client to send you the version string on each request, and have your API work based off that.

Best practise however is to think of this in the opposite direction. Rather than delivering different results to clients based on their version. Best thing to do is to version your API after a breaking change, like this:

```
https://api.mydomain.com/v1/user
https://api.mydomain.com/v2/user
https://api.mydomain.com/v3/user
```

The new version of the iOS app will point to the latest API, while the old ones still point to the older API. You can add monitoring to the API's and when there has been no traffic to /v1/ after a number of weeks, you can remove that version to free up the resources, and clean up outdated code. Rinse and repeat